How to select today date and time in date picker field by default
How can I select today's date and time in oracle apex in a form field Date picker by default.
I tried to select "default" value but it doesn't show when opening the form in update mode
I tried the first choice, the static value SYSDATE but it still doesn't show
I also tried the default SQL QUERY :
SELECT SYSDATE FROM DUAL; 

but it also doesn't show the date.
For "time" I enabled the option to show time in the field and tried to select date and time but it also doesn't show the date and time.
What is missing please and thank you in advance

In APEX all page items are strings in the DOM. So, to get a value in a page item, make sure you have a string representation of the date value you want. That implies including the time portion.
Here is one way. Use a PL/SQL Expression to return a DATE in a format that includes the time portion.

Output:

So... why did the 2 solutions you mention not work ?

"Static Value". That is just text. If you put static value "SYSDATE" then the value of the page item will be "SYSDATE", not the actual sysdate... I suggest you try this with a page item of type text.

SQL Query SELECT SYSDATE FROM DUAL. As I stated, page items in the DOM are just text. That means that you're relying on the session settings to do an implicit conversion to text. In a database session, the default setting for date format is the parameter NLS_DATE_FORMAT. In Oracle APEX, this can be manipulated in Application > Shared Components > Application Definition > Globalization > "Application Date Format". Change the format mask for this attribute to a date format with a time portion and the SELECT SYSDATE FROM DUAL query will produce a value that includes the time portion and can be used as date picker item source.


